# Evaluation of the integral $\oint _{ C }^{ }{ \frac { 2{ z }^{ 2 }+5 }{ { \left( z+2 \right) }^{ 3 }\left( { z }^{ 2 }+4 \right) { z }^{ 2 } } dz } $

Tags: integration, complex-integration

It seems that to  find residue and then applying  the Residue Theorem" is too long . I'd like to know is there a briefer way to evaluate this integral apart from applying the Residue Theorem?
$$\oint _{ C }^{  }{ \frac { 2{ z }^{ 2 }+5 }{ { \left( z+2 \right)  }^{ 3 }\left( { z }^{ 2 }+4 \right) { z }^{ 2 } } dz } $$
where contour here is  $\left| z-2i \right| =6$

Comment: No there is no other way. By the way, it's not "that long", come on ! Be brave ;-)

Comment: Too long? Seriously? Then you will never learn the technique. Perhaps the best way for you is to look up the answer in the back of the book -- that's pretty quick.

Comment: Why the vote to close? It was good psychology to ask this question.

Comment: @MPW, yes sir, finding residues is too long process,try to find one of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is an easier way here. By the residue theorem, your contour integral equals $2\pi i$ times the sum of the residues inside $C.$ But there are no singurities beyond those inside $C.$ Thus any contour containing $C$ can make the same claim. So if $R$ large, say $R>100,$ we have

$$\int_C { \frac { 2{ z }^{ 2 }+5 }{ { \left( z+2 \right)  }^{ 3 }\left( { z }^{ 2 }+4 \right) { z }^{ 2 } } dz } = \int_{|z|=R}{ \frac { 2{ z }^{ 2 }+5 }{ { \left( z+2 \right)  }^{ 3 }\left( { z }^{ 2 }+4 \right) { z }^{ 2 } } dz }.$$

Now consider the contour integral on the right. In absolute value, it is no more than $2\pi R$ times the maximum of the integrand in absolute value. This maximum, as a function of $R,$ is on the order of $\dfrac{ R^2}{R^3\cdot R^2\cdot R^2}.$ It follows that the limit of the integral on the right, as $R\to \infty,$ is $0.$ Well, if the limit of something that is constant is equal to $0,$ then that something is constantly $0.$ Hence the contour integral on the left equals $0.$

Comment: @thank you for the solution, but it is still unclear to me, perhaps I don't familiar with such tricks. Can we draw a conclusion, that whenever contour encloses all poles we should apply Cauchy? Can you please  add here the theorem that you have applied ?

Comment: Would the downvoter care to share the wisdom behind the vote?

Comment: Both $\int_C, \int_{|z|=R}$ are equal to $2\pi i$ times the sum of residues inside $C.$ Thus the two integrals are equal. That's all. This is why $\int_C$ equals the limit of the latter integral as $R\to \infty.$. This idea is very much worth learning, but it applies mostly to rational functions.

Comment: I edited my answer and hope improved it.